# Arrayelements as counters

Tags: java

I'm learning java and have some misunderstanding  about array elements:

```
import java.util.Random;
class One {
  public static void main (String[]args) {
    Random R1 = new Random();
    int mat [] = new int [6];
    for ( int chance =0; chance<99; chance++ ) {            
        ++mat[1+R1.nextInt(5)];         
    }
    System.out.println("M\tNumber");
    for(int M =1;M <mat.length;M++) {       
      System.out.println(M  + "\t" + mat[M]);
    }
  }
}
```

And after running this code I got something like:

```
  M Number
    1   30
    2   15
    3   17
    4   23
    5   14
```

I did a lot of attempts and usually Number <=20, which is a bit confusing for me cause I assighn chance <99 hence I asume it should be a bigger number in general. Could you point on my mistake?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: I don't think so.

Comment: 20 is about right, though, if you throw 99 balls into 5 buckets. Significantly bigger numbers would be quite unlikely.

Comment: "hence I asume it should be a bigger number in general." Why would you assume that? The sum of the numbers should always be 99, just as it is in your example: 30+15+17+23+14=99.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. That is quite confusing.

Comment: your numbers add up to 99 - so getting like 80 would mean the other 4 numbers would be pretty low, which I guess is statistically less likely.

Comment: Beyond that: look into your *naming*. R1 ... says nothing. mat ... says nothing. Use names that tell about the thing behind the name, like "randomGenerator". And learn to properly indent your source code please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Meaning: you are showing code, and the actual results. But what are your expectations - what is your actual question to us? (and hint: if you expected the numbers to all be ~20 ... well, run often enough ... and you will get there. It is called *law of **big** numbers* for a reason)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no mistake. 
It is very likely that numbers will be about 20 because:

You repeat the following sequence 99 times:
1. Get one random(one of six) element from array.
2. Increase element value (plus one).

Let's assume (of course it doesn't) that random method works in the way it gets for 99 execution :
20 times value 0
20 times value 1 
20 times value 2
20 times value 3
20 times value 4
19 times value 5

So we get:
20 in first array element
20 in second array element
and so on...

So, to get bigger number you need to decrease array length or change condition in for loop to bigger "chance" number (in your case: for ( int chance =0; chance<200; chance++ ) ).